# Primefaces Calendar select week instead day

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I am using primefaces calendar. I want to select a week instead of selecting a day. 
I found out it was possible in primefaces 2.0 to have an array of days in backbean instead of one date object. I am using version 4 and it is not possible anymore. I was thinking if i could use the week number as the pattern and use the popup calendar it will show the week number in the text field. However it worked first time i tried, but second time i want to choose a date it will only display "w". Is the anyway to make this work? 
i was thinking to use a  converter which convert the week number to a date because my theory is that calendar cant convert the week number to date by it self. I am not familiar using converters? I will appreciate any help.

```
<p:calendar value="#{bean.date}" locale="en"  pattern="w">
```